# Using powershell to silently install software when verification is required

Tags: powershell, nsis

It's a simple script, I just need to install several software on a couple of machines.

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\executable.exe /S /D=C:\Program Files\Executable\
C:\Users\user\Downloads\executable1.exe /S /D=C:\Program Files\Executable1\
C:\Users\user\Downloads\executable2.exe /S /D=C:\Program Files\Executable2\
```

However, our admins require you to select a reason from a dropdown and enter your password every time you need admin access to do something.

Is there a workaround for this?

Edit: as is now, it looks like it's installing, but it fails. If I take the silent off, the pop up comes up and after entering the proper values, it'll proceed with the installation.

Comment: A reason? Is Windows asking for a reason? What does this dialog look like? And please post some code...

Comment: No, I think the admins just have a group policy setup so that you can't use administrative rights without giving a reason. It's an IT Security Policy pop up. that asks for confirmation.

I don't really have any code other than running the executable silently

Comment: You could maybe post a screenshot of this dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for this...

```
"our admins require you to select a reason from a dropdown and enter your password every time you need admin access to do something.

Is there a workaround for this?"
```

So, they are monitoring install events using native Windows polices or a 3rdP tool to prevent unauthorized installs???

Soooooo....
you are asking the forum members to help you with code to circumvent/violates  your organization's security / risk management policy???
In most orgs, violating security / risk policies is an RPE (resume producing event). Should you not be talking to your orgs policy makers first?

Anyways, if you are authorized to do this install work, the approach would be no different than trying to push data to a form. You trap the form Window, enumerate the input boxes to be able to know what they are and take needed actions. PoSH, out of box, is really not designed for that sort of thing. You need a tool that can programmatically deal with GUI and potentially a GUI which does not have a known interface to automate against.

Look to tools like WASP, it's a bit dated, but may work for you.

WASP is a PowerShell snapin for Windows Automation tasks like selecting windows and controls and sending mouse and keyboard events. We have  automation cmdlets like Select-Window, Select-Control, Send-Keys, Send-Click, Get-WindowPosition, Set-WindowPosition, Set-WindowActive, Remove-Window ... etc.

http://wasp.codeplex.com

Or AutoIT

https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit

BTW, if you are trying to do this in the context of a user on a remote host, PoSH will not let you do this, it is restricted by Windows Security Principal boundaries. Tools like PSExec, can help here AutoIt.

Answer (score 1):

Just run PowerShell with an administrative rights:

1. Right click PowerShell
2. Select 'Run as administrator'

Or:

1. Use 'Shift + Ctrl + Click' to open PowerShell.

Both commands do the same and open the program with elevated rights. This prevents UAC from popping up because PowerShell will already be running with elevated rights.

Comment: The question is tagged with NSIS, so it can be assumed that OP wants to run the script on a client machine.